# Python program cannot fetch href from webpage when i am using my Uni Network which have proxy

Tags: python, proxy, beautifulsoup

I am writing a python program to fetch all hyperlinks from a Url provided .
It was working fine when I run it at home and my Hostel room with internet connection without proxy But when i tried running the program at my University Network having a proxy setting a got this error :

```
*'Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "myurl.py", line 26, in <module>
   main()
  File "myurl.py", line 24, in main
   process(url)
   File "myurl.py", line 7, in process
   page = urllib.urlopen(url)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 84, in urlopen
   return opener.open(url)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 205, in open
   return getattr(self, name)(url)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 342, in open_http
   h.endheaders(data)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 940, in endheaders
   self._send_output(message_body)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 803, in _send_output
   self.send(msg)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 755, in send
   self.connect()
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 736, in connect
   self.timeout, self.source_address)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 551, in create_connection
   for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
   IOError: [Errno socket error] [Errno -2] Name or service not known''*
```

My Program code is :

```
import sys
import urllib
import urlparse

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
def process(url):
page = urllib.urlopen(url)
text = page.read()
page.close()
soup = BeautifulSoup(text)
with open('s.txt','w') as file:
        for tag in soup.findAll('a', href=True):
            tag['href'] = urlparse.urljoin(url, tag['href'])
            print tag['href']
            file.write('\n')
            file.write(tag['href'])


def main():
    if len(sys.argv) == 1:
       print 'No url !!'
       sys.exit(1)
for url in sys.argv[1:]:
```

Answer (score 0):

The code works fine without a proxy involved. The problem is not your code as much as it is your other network variables. Untrusted proxies, other system settings concerning your connection to said proxy, etc. Eliminate your system and the proxy in question from the equation, and test further.